# How to select the most recent records from a table by DateTime in Slick, by nested query

Tags: scala, jodatime, slick

How to get the last (x) number of records, according to a date time field. 
by using Slick, Scala and JodaTime library? 
as the following code want to implement the *last(x)* definition for explaining the question.

```
import org.joda.time._
import com.github.tototoshi.slick.PostgresJodaSupport._

 def last(x: Int): DateTime=???

 val callInfo = callTable.filter( _.calltime >= last(x))
```

Is it possible to implement something like the following for the last method? that aimed to result into a nested query

```
def last(x: Int) = {
    callTable.sortBy(_.calltime.desc).take(x).sortBy ( _.calltime.asc).take(1).map{ _.calltime}
  }
```

this return a Query[Rep[Option[DateTime]], Option[DateTime], Seq] not DateTime!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is to sort calltime and then take the desired number of elements:

```
callTable.sortBy(_.calltime.desc).take(x)
```

The complete code would be something like:

```
def last(x): DateTime = callTable.sortBy(_.calltime.desc).take(x).drop(x-1).map(_.calltime).headOption

val callInfo = last(10).map { lastDate => callTable.filter(_.calltime > lastDate).list
```

Comment: I appreciate your correct answer, but taking your answer, I want to implement something like 
   def last(x: Int) = {
     callTable.sortBy(_.calltime.desc).take(x).sortBy ( _.calltime.asc ).take(1).map{ _.calltime}
   }
gut to get the Date Time to compare is it possible.

Comment: @ALMEK I think I misunderstood your question. What is the x in your exampe? And what is the column type in the db table?

Comment: I am sorry, I might have not stated clear
i want that to compile into a nested query,  the column is DateTime and the x  is Int as you have expected correctly

Comment: You have got that :), but the firstOption property giving me an error, that is not slick 3.1.1. , right? 
actually i discovered that i only doesn't know how to take the first option.

Comment: @ALMEK it changed to headOption on slick 3

Comment: Ok! and how to implement that?

Comment: Not working, that will only work after running the result.headOption,  
as example db.run(last(10).result.head),